# How to resize image in codeigniter according to given dimensions

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have added the code for resizing images in codeigniter.

```
$configs['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$configs['source_image']    = './userpics/'.$new_name;
$configs['new_image'] = './userpics/userthumb/'.$new_name;
$configs['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
$configs['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;

$configs['quality']  = '100';
$configs['width']   = 80;
$configs['height']  = 80;
```

But images are coming in 80*45 or 80*60. Please let me know any solution so that i can show in proper dimensions.

Comment: Try with `$configs['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;`

Comment: In this images looks compressed. Any other way

Answer (score 0):

pl refer

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html

maintain_ratio : TRUE/FALSE - Specifies whether to maintain the original aspect ratio when resizing or use hard values.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = "Mention your source location here";
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['height']   = "New Width";
$config['width'] = "New Height";
$config['new_image'] = "destination location";//you should have write permission here..
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

[Check This](http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-resize-an-image-in-codeIgniter)